# biblatex-publist makes me coauthor of entries I'm not author of

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-publist

When writing my cv, I wanna include some bibentries for my own papers, but also some other describing some courses I've taken. My strategy is to put those courses taken in a special class (e.g. `@book`) and print separate bibliographies as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Curriculm Vitae}
\author{R. Reventlov Giskard}

\usepackage%
    [backend=biber,%
    style=publist]% 
    {biblatex}

\plauthorname[R. Giskard]{Reventlov}

\addbibresource{articles.bib}
\addbibresource{courses.bib}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\nocite{*}

%   MY ARTICLES
\printbibliography[title={Published Articles}, type=article]


%   COURSES [BOOKS] BY OTHERS
\printbibliography[title={Courses Taken}, type=book]

\end{document}
```

The `\printbibliography` commands should print something like:

> **Published Articles**
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZCDF.png) **2006** (with R. Daneel Olivaw). "The Three Laws of Robotics Revisited".
>
> [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557647/154737) **2005**. "The Zeroth Law of Robotics".

> **Courses Taken**
>
> [3](http://txt.do/1fc7k) **2004** Susan Calvin. *Practical Aspects of Robotics*.
>
> [4](http://txt.do/1fcz2) **2003** Han Fastolfe and Vasilia Fastolfe. *How to read and influence the emotions of humans and robots*.

Instead, they fourth entry is mistakenly printed as follows:

> [4](http://txt.do/1fcz2) **2003** (with Han Fastolfe and Vasilia Fastolfe). *How to read and influence the emotions of humans and robots*.

How can I prevent `biblatex-publist` from implicitly making me coauthor of this fourth entry (or of all `@book` entries for that matter)?

#### Note 1

In my full code I declare a special entry type `@course` as follows:

```
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{course}{book}
```

and then call:

```
\printbibliography[title={Courses Taken}, type=course]
```

In both cases, the error persists.

#### Note 2

The output without `style=publist` would be something like:

> **Published Articles**
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZCDF.png) R. Reventlov Giskard and R. Daneel Olivaw (2006). "The Three Laws of Robotics Revisited".
>
> [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557647/154737) R. Reventlov Giskard  (2005). "The Zeroth Law of Robotics".

> **Courses Taken**
>
> [3](http://txt.do/1fc7k) Susan Calvin (2004). *Practical Aspects of Robotics*.
>
> [4](http://txt.do/1fcz2) Han Fastolfe and Vasilia Fastolfe (2003). *How to read and influence the emotions of humans and robots*.

#### OP Edit 1

I have tested the following version of the code provided by [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557647/154737)
(the only changes being removing the "R." from "R. Giskard Reventlov" and adding "Susan Calvin" as coauthor of "appleby"): [txt.do/1fc7k](http://txt.do/1fc7k)

However, the output is:

[image]

Notice that the co-authorship that matters here is that of the "appleby" entry. It isn't supposed to say "(with ...)" because Giskard (the `pluauthorname`) is not coauthor in the entry "appleby".

Here's the log file, in case it is of interest: [txt.do/1fcz2](http://txt.do/1fcz2)

#### OP Edit 2

After having installed a vanilla TeX Live, as recommended in [@moewe's comment to his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557647/154737), we seem to be one step away from solving the issue. The same input returns the following output:

[image]

(Highlights are mine.)

Here is the log file: [txt.do/1fg0o](http://txt.do/1fg0o)

Just in case, I wouldn't mind loosing the *et al* feature since I'm setting `maxnames=99`.

Comment: Please consider posting *complete* examples including example `.bib` entries in the future. We don't have your `.bib` files and having to make up suitable entries is quite a boring and unnecessary task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** As mentioned by [JSpitzm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19291/jspitzm), the developer of `biblatex-publist`, version 1.20 with a fix for this slightly counter-intuitive behaviour is out now.

---

Previously (< v1.20) `biblatex-publist` assumed you are the co-author of the works listed. If I understand all the work the style does the information whether or not a `\plauthorname` is present in a name is available, we just need to make use of it.

The trick is to check `nonplauthors`/`nonpleditors` against `listtotal`. If they are equal `\plauthorname` is not amongst the authors/editors. In that case we avoid the "with" and the parentheses.

The entire definition of `bpl:handlenames` is quite full on, here we only added the two `\ifthenelse{\value{nonpl#1s}=\value{listtotal}}` tests to the original definition from `publist.bbx`.

The code below requires `biblatex-publist` v.1.18 (2020/07/31). There may not be an error with older versions, but the output is probably not going to be as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage%
    [backend=biber,%
    style=publist]% 
    {biblatex}

\plauthorname[Giskard]{Reventlov}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro{bpl:handlenames}[1][author]{%
    \bpl@ifplauthor{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartfamily}%
       {\global\toggletrue{isplauthor}\stepcounter{pl#1}}%
       {\global\togglefalse{isplauthor}}%
    %
    % Calculate real list stop
    \ifnumless{\value{liststop}}{\value{maxnames}}
         {\setcounter{realliststop}{\theliststop}}
         {\setcounter{realliststop}{\value{minnames}}}%
    %
    % First case: plauthorhandling=highlight
    \if@hlauthor%
        % Highlight plauthor(s)
        \usebibmacro{bpl:omissiondelim}[#1]%
        \iftoggle{isplauthor}{%
            \plauthorhl{%
                \if@givenfirst% given name first
                    \ifgiveninits
                        {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                        {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
                    \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}%
                        {}%
                        {\namepartprefix\addspace}%
                    \namepartfamily%
                \else% family name first
                    \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}%
                        {}%
                        {\namepartprefix\addspace}%
                    \namepartfamily%
                    \ifgiveninits
                        {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                        {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiven\isdot\addspace}}%
                \fi
            }%
            \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}{}{\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}%
        }{%
           \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{realliststop}}{}{%
             \if@givenfirst% given name first
                 \ifgiveninits
                     {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                     {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
                 \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}%
                     {}%
                     {\namepartprefix\addspace}%
                 \namepartfamily%
             \else% family name first
                 \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}%
                       {}%
                       {\namepartprefix\addspace}%
                 \namepartfamily%
                 \ifgiveninits
                    {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                    {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\addcomma\addspace\namepartgiven\isdot\addspace}}%
             \fi
           }%
           \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
        }%
    %
    % Second case: plauthorhandling=omit
    \else% \if@hlauthor false
        \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}%
            {\ifthenelse{\value{nonpl#1s}>0}%
                 {\ifthenelse{\value{pl#1s}=0}
                    {}
                    {\bibopenparen\bibstring{with}\addspace}}%
                 {}%
             \iftoggle{isplauthor}%
                 {\global\toggletrue{plauthorprecedes}}%
                 {\global\togglefalse{plauthorprecedes}}%
            }%
            {}%
        % Exclude omitted author
        \iftoggle{isplauthor}%
            {% <- TRUE condition
              \global\toggletrue{hadplauthor}%
            }% <- end TRUE condition
            {% <- FALSE condition
              \stepcounter{nonpl#1}%
              \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}%
                   {\global\togglefalse{hadplauthor}}%
                   {%
                     \iftoggle{plauthorprecedes}%
                         {}%
                         {%
                           \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{realliststop}}{}{%
                              \ifnumless{\value{nonpl#1}}{\value{nonpl#1s}}%
                                 {\multinamedelim}%
                                 {\printdelim[#1]{bplfinalnamedelim}}%
                            }%
                         }%
                   }%
             \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{realliststop}}{}{%
              \ifgiveninits
                  {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiveni}{}{\namepartgiveni\addspace}}%
                  {\ifdefvoid{\namepartgiven}{}{\namepartgiven\addspace}}%
              \ifdefvoid{\namepartprefix}{}{\namepartprefix\addspace}%
              \global\togglefalse{plauthorprecedes}%
              \namepartfamily%
             }%
            }% <- end FALSE condition
        %
        \usebibmacro{name:andothers}%
        \ifthenelse{\value{nonpl#1s}>0\AND\value{listcount}=\value{liststop}}%
            {\ifthenelse{\value{pl#1s}=0}
               {}
               {\unspace\bibcloseparen}}%
            {}%
    \fi% end of \if@hlauthor else condition
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {2001},
}
@book{bppleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby and Someone Else},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {2002},
}
@book{cppleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Cppleby and Someone Else and A. Third Person},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {2003},
}
@article{reventlov:2,
  author  = {Giskard Reventlov and Someone Else},
  title   = {Turtles},
  date    = {2012},
}
@article{reventlov:1,
  author  = {Giskard Reventlov},
  title   = {Turtles},
  date    = {2011},
}
@article{reventlov:3,
  author  = {Giskard Reventlov and Ann Uthor and Bann Tuthor},
  title   = {Turtles},
  date    = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

%   MY ARTICLES
\printbibliography[title={Published Articles}, type=article]

%   COURSES [BOOKS] BY OTHERS
\printbibliography[title={Courses Taken}, type=book]
\end{document}
```

[image: 2013 (with Ann Uthor and Bann Tuthor). “Turtles”. In://2003 Humphrey Cppleby, Someone Else, and A. Third Person. On the Importance of the Civil Service.]

Comment: Thanks, @moewe. Could you explain a bit how the code works? The problem persists for more than two authors. In fact, there has never been a problem with only one author: it has never been parenthesised nor prefixed by "with".

Comment: @lfba As I briefly alluded in the answer body, `biblatex-publist` already counts the number of non-pl authors/editors. If we compare that number to the total number of authors/editors and they are the same, there was no pl author/editor and we thus don't print 'with'. If I change the `author = {Humphrey Appleby},` to `author  = {Humphrey Appleby and Bernard Woolley},` in `appleby` I still get no 'with' for the authors. Can you please explain what exactly goes wrong when you write `author  = {Humphrey Appleby and Bernard Woolley},`  in my MWE?

Comment: @lfba I only just realised that there is something odd going on with "R. Giskard Reventlov" in the example. That appears to be a bug in `biblatex-publist` that I just reported at https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/issues/24. So if you are asking about the superfluous "R. Giskard Reventlov" in the first entry, that should explain things. For the time being take a different name that doesn't contain initials and you should be good.

Comment: Quick update on the bug mention above: It was fixed shortly after it was reported. The version on GitHub already works fine, not sure when the update will hit CTAN.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe. The problem is not with the `@article` entry "reventlov", but with the `@book` entry "appleby". See my **OP Edit 1** for more details.

Comment: @lfba Your version of `biblatex-publist` is outdated (you have `publist.bbx 2018/03/01 v.1.9`, mine is `publist.bbx 2020/07/10 v.1.17`). Your old version does not calculate `nonplauthors`/`nonpleditors`. You could try grabbing the `.bbx` and `.cbx` from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-publist and dropping it into the same directory as your main `.tex` file to get a newer version. This may not work if `biblatex-publist` depends on a newer `biblatex` version than you have. ...

Comment: ... In that case you may have to think about switching from the TeX live from the Debian/Ubuntu repositories to a vanilla TeX live, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864. (In case it was unclear, I tested your MWE and I got the expected/correct output.)

Comment: Thanks for your support, @moewe. We seem to be one step away from the solution. Please, check my **OP Edit 2**.

Comment: @lfba Oh, there was a `biblatex-publist` update changing some bits of `bpl:handlenames`. The update also makes what we want a bit easier. Try again, please.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, @moewe. However, I already removed "et al" by commenting out `\usebibmacro{name:andothers}`. So I take this to be solved.

Comment: @lfba I have updated the code example and example image. That is the output I get with `biblatex-publist` v.1.18 (the current release version on CTAN) and `biblatex` 3.14/Biber 2.14 (also current CTAN releases). I think that is the desired output and there is no 'et al.'. I'm not quite sure what didn't work for you. However, please do not just remove `\usebibmacro{name:andothers}` as that will simply remove the ability to properly deal with 'et al.' if necessary. I rejected your edit to the answer to that effect, because I don't want to suggest that.

Comment: Everything is working perfectly now, @moewe. Thanks.

Comment: @lfba Very odd. As you can see in the edit history the relevant code was not touched in the edit. I only added a few more test cases.

Comment: FYI I have now fixed this in `biblatex-publist` itself, for version 1.20 (under development). So if you take https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/master/publist.bbx it should work as well

Comment: `biblatex-publist` 1.20, which fixes the issue reported here, has now been released.

Comment: @JSpitzm Thanks for the heads-up. Answer updated-

Answer (score 1):

This is not a case `biblatex-publist` is currently prepared for. However, it strikes me you could (mis-)use the `@review` type for this type of task, which does not consider `plauthor`. Or you define a new driver `@course` on the base of `@review`.

For the usage of `@review`, please refer to the manual.